# foreach is not working while trying to get students

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
echo "<pre>";  print_r($jobbrnchesids); exit;

<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
           [id_branch] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_branch] => 1
        )
    )
```

From the above array, i am getting job id branches.. Now i am trying to Get the students who are with these branches.
i have tried like this way but it something is going wrong unable to debug can anyone help me out.

```
$studentBranch = '';
  foreach ($jobbrnchesids  as $k => $v){
      $stuBranch = $conn->query("SELECT student_pid FROM tbl_students
                    WHERE graduation_branch = ".$v." ");
       $studentsWithBranches[] = $stuBranch->fetch_assoc();
   }
echo "<pre>";  print_r($studentsWithBranches); exit;
```

Comment: $v['id_branch']

Comment: Use parameterized queries.

Comment: it working fine thank you. and it is splitting in arrays can i store all students in one array..?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed:- `and it is splitting in arrays can i store all students in one array`? what this mean?

Comment: @chris85  i am agreed with you. Also

Comment: see my answer once i apppriciate your help guys. @Anant

Comment: You should use `JOIN`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `$v` it need to be `$v['id_branch']`

Answer (score 3):

missing array index 'id_branch'

Try:

```
$stuBranch = $conn->query("SELECT student_pid FROM tbl_students
                WHERE graduation_branch = ".$v['id_branch']." ");
```

Answer (score 2):

Reduce your overhead by doing the following:

```
 $branchIds = array_column($jobbrnchesids,"id_branch");

 $result = $conn->query("SELECT student_pid FROM tbl_students
            WHERE graduation_branch IN (".implode(",",$branchIds.")");
 $studentsWithBranches = $result?$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC):[];
```

[`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) Returns the values from a single column in the input array

Answer (score 2):

```
$studentBranch = '';
foreach ($jobbrnchesids as $k => $v) {
    $stuBranch = $conn->query("SELECT student_pid FROM tbl_students WHERE graduation_branch = '" . ['id_branch'] . "'");
    $studentsWithBranches[] = $stuBranch->fetch_assoc();
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($studentsWithBranches);
exit;
```